# QWebView not loading images properly

Tags: qt, qwebview, qprinter

I created an application that uses QWebView to create a template and then prints it as a pdf file.
In the view I set a background image to the body and when excecuting the program, the first time I print the pdf, the image is not being printed in the pdf. Then, I print again the same pdf and the image appears. Thus for all the subsecuent prints.
So, it doesn't work just for the first print.

I debbuged the html code and the backgrund image is allways being set.

For printing the pdf file I use this:

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);

printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(76.2,180),QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer.setPageMargins(27,11.2,4,4.4,QPrinter::Millimeter);

QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer);

if (dialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
    QWebView *view = new QWebView();
    QUrl url(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
    view->setHtml(cheque,url);

    view->print(&printer);
}
```

Where **cheque** is the html template

Comment: Do you create a new `QWebView` instanse (`QWebView *view = new QWebView();`) for each subsequent print as in the question code or `view` is reused (stored as a class member)?

Comment: From `QWebView::setHtml` documentation: "The html is loaded immediately; external objects are loaded asynchronously." I'm guessing when you call `view->setHtml`, image is not loaded yet. This could be the problem.

Comment: thanks guys, solved it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that objects are being loaded asynchronously in QWebView's. So I declared the QWebView before calling the QPrintDialog.

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);

printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(76.2,180),QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer.setPageMargins(27,11.2,4,4.4,QPrinter::Millimeter);

QWebView *view = new QWebView();
QUrl url(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
view->setHtml(cheque,url);

QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer);

if (dialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted){

    view->print(&printer);
}
```

Comment: This solution is not safe from the point of view of time race conditions.
Of course typically the print dialog takes quite large amount of time, so `QWebView` can finish loading its content. However it a bug. The print should be started only when the page is loaded. The signal `QWebView::loadFinished(bool)` can used to do it properly.